# Easy way for (Node)+JS Voice calls in Webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, socket.io

I would make a Voice Chat (for example like discord). The Problem is: I don't wont to make this with WebRTC peer2peer. More like this: Client (Microphone in Webbrowser) -> NodeJS "Server" -> other Clients (listeners)

I want to perform this in realtime. My Question: How I can create this? With WebRTC Extensions for NodeJS? SocketIO? Other ideas?

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you cna use is an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) (Selective Forwarding Unit). With this solution the sender will only need to send once stream to the server and the server handles all the retransmission to the other users. There are several tools to implement this:

- [Janus-gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/)
- [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/)
- [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/)

[Here is a simple example project](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms)  of how videoconferencing is implemented with mediasoup with a NodeJS server using SocketIO.